# How to export plotly plots, tabs and images into a single html

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is a way to export multiple plotly plots, tabs and images into a single HTML file.
In detail the problem is this. I want to create a standalone .exe file with python able to plot several graphs and images, given some input files containing the data; writing code with PySimpleGUI for the GUI.
But once the several interactive graphs, tabs and images are plotted in a window, I would like to add in the window two buttons to export these data respectively in a excel file (so with no interactivity) and in a HTML file (to keep interactivity).
The first point is no trouble for me: I use xlsxwriter to export images and graphs as images. The problem is the second point: I would like to export all these data keeping interactions in graphs in a single HTML with a certain design I choose. Remember the fact that I want to build a standalone .exe file, because this program will run in a PC with Python not installed.
My question is this: is there some python library or html writer in python I can use to do this?

P.S.: plotly graphs are not subplots of a single plots but each one is a single plot, each one will have its own zoom etc. commands.

Comment: You can save individual plots in the HTML format and then build a single webpage embedding the plots as iframes.

Comment: Can I do this using only Python libraries?

Comment: I think so. You can create and save plots using plotly, and then use some templating engine such as Jinja to generate an HTML file from a template, inserting the plots in the right places.